# Is it necessary to do entity relationship validation in the business logic layer when using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, backend

Let's say I have a book database server using MySQL. There are two entities

1. Book
2. Author
   With one to many relationship between them, one author can have many books.

There is a route in the backend to create new books with an author. The body of the request is the following

```
{
   bookTitle: "title",
   authorId: 1
}
```

Is it necessary for the business logic layer to first check if there is an record in the Author table with authorId = 1 before inserting the new book? Or leaving this validation to the database itself because it will throw a foreign error anyway.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *Or leaving this validation to the database itself because it will throw a foreign error anyway.* o_O This is a type of client-side validation - the presence of the referential value can be checked by both quering this value (zero output rows means that the value is absent) and by insertion (which either fails or returns zero rows effected output when the value is absent). But "insertion" check needs less queries amount.

Comment: I don't think this model works well when a book is jointly authored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should validate this. One way to do this in mysql automatically is to make sure you have the correct foreign keys setup.

Even with all of that correctly done, it's still a good idea for your backend/api to first grab the author from the database so you can return a more specific error if it didn't exist.

In most real-world applications, usually there's also permissions involved. Can all your users insert books for *any* author?

Comment: Thanks, it's convincing to me. I just made up this simple example, with no permissions involved.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* push the "business logic" into a Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ... (IN _title VARCHAR(...), IN _author VARCHAR(...))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO authors ...
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
    INSERT INTO books
        (title, author_id)
        VALUES (_title, LAST_INSERT_ID() );
END;
```

See the manual on how to get the id from the Upsert.

If, as P.Salmon points out, you need a many-to-many mapping table between books and authors, then there would be 3 statements.